# Parsing text to XML format

Tags: python, xml

Im not sure if this is a JSON file or what type of data structure, but I need to parse these format to XML using python language.

```
(Table){
   classA= "false"
   classB= "150538"
   classC= "AE_T_C"
   classD= "510150 DLCX DEPOSITION"
   classE= "233344"
   classF= "516"
   classG= "150131"
   classH= "CARJOB"
   classI= "23001367"
   classJ= "960"
   classK= "16"
   classL= "true"
   classM= "P_GENERIC_HARMONY.2"
 }
 (Table){
   LetterA= "true"
   LetterB= "15"
   LetterC= "x"
   LetterD= "Carbon"
   LetterE= "44"
   LetterF= "test"
   LetterG= "Dump"
   LetterH= "NA"
   LetterI= "2"
   LetterJ= "9"
   LetterK= "1"
   LetterL= "done"
   LetterM= "test"
 }
 .
 .
 .
```

Here is my current script to parse JSON File but I think it is not a JSON, Im still confused how could I parse it:

```
import json
import urllib
import dicttoxml

filename = 'c:/myFile'
file = open(filename,"r") 
lines = file.read() 

content = lines
obj = json.loads(content)
print(obj)

content = lines
obj = json.loads(content)
print(obj)

xml = dicttoxml.dicttoxml(obj)
print(xml)
```

Is there any way or suggestion to parse these kind of file?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: It's not JSON and you couldn't parse it like JSON.

Comment: so do have any idea or suggestion? or any way so that I can easily parse it to XML

Comment: It is not JSON but does look a bit like it and can be converted easily into JSON. do you have many files like this or is it the only one. If it's the only one 30 second job to convert to json by hand.

Comment: All of them has the same format but different values, but all I need is to parse it in XML format. You may see my updated format file above..

Comment: I updated my answer to make the `xml` a bit more structured if you have knowledge of the contents of each table before hand. Take a look if you might need this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick little script for this, it depends on the **[`xmltodict`](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict)** module which helps in transforming a `dict` to an `xml` file:

```
import xmltodict
mydict = {}
# I added the contents to a file named 'afile.txt'
with open("afile.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        # ignore lines containing a bracket
        if "{" not in line and "}" not in line:
            # Split string and remove whitespaces
            linesplit = line.split("=")
            mydict[linesplit[0].strip()]=linesplit[1][:-1]
# define xml root tag
root = {
    'body': mydict
}
# parse (or unparce) to xml
print xmltodict.unparse(root, pretty=True)
```

Running this with the (initial) contents you provided prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<body>
    <classL> "true"</classL>
    <classM> "P_GENERIC_HARMONY.2"</classM>
    <classJ> "960"</classJ>
    <classK> "16"</classK>
    <classH> "CARJOB"</classH>
    <classI> "23001367"</classI>
    <classF> "516"</classF>
    <classG> "150131"</classG>
    <classD> "510150 DLCX DEPOSITION"</classD>
    <classE> "233344"</classE>
    <classB> "150538"</classB>
    <classC> "AE_T_C"</classC>
    <classA> "false"</classA>
</body>
```

Which does the job. If by any chance you happen to know the contents of each **Table** beforehand you could also define a list holding these labels and make that `xml` file look more structured:

```
# define the appropriate labels:
TableValues = ['Class', 'Letter']

# and create the dictionary based on these tags:
# this uses a dictionary comprehension in a dictionary 
# comprehension. Comprehensive stuff.
new_root = {
    'body': {
        label: {
            key: value 
            for key, value in mydict.iteritems() 
            if label.lower() in key.lower()
        } 
        for label in TableValues
     }
}    

print xmltodict.unparse(new_root, pretty=True)
```

Executing this with the added content you provided yields a more structured result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<body>
    <Class>
        <classL>"true"</classL>
        <classM>"P_GENERIC_HARMONY.2"</classM>
        <classJ>"960"</classJ>
        <classK>"16"</classK>
        <classH>"CARJOB"</classH>
        <classI>"23001367"</classI>
        <classF>"516"</classF>
        <classG>"150131"</classG>
        <classD>"510150 DLCX DEPOSITION"</classD>
        <classE>"233344"</classE>
        <classB>"150538"</classB>
        <classC>"AE_T_C"</classC>
        <classA>"false"</classA>
    </Class>
    <Letter>
        <LetterG>"Dump"</LetterG>
        <LetterF>"test"</LetterF>
        <LetterE>"44"</LetterE>
        <LetterD>"Carbon"</LetterD>
        <LetterC>"x"</LetterC>
        <LetterB>"15"</LetterB>
        <LetterA>"true"</LetterA>
        <LetterM>"test"</LetterM>
        <LetterL>"done"</LetterL>
        <LetterK>"1"</LetterK>
        <LetterJ>"9"</LetterJ>
        <LetterI>"2"</LetterI>
        <LetterH>"NA"</LetterH>
    </Letter>
</body>
```